# Insert random data into a table that has foreign key

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table "User" (`idUser`, `name`, `departmentId`) and another table "Department" (`idDepartment`, `name`).

I would like to insert random data into table `User`, but it would be necessary to consider only the departments previously inserted.

I think it would be something like:

```
INSERT INTO User (idUser, name, departmentId)
VALUES (seq_user.nextVal, 'random name', FK_RANDOM_DEPARTMENT);
```

How can I generate this 'random name' and only use departments that I have already inserted?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO User 
(idUser, name, departmentId)
VALUES 
(seq_user.nextVal,
 DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('L', 20), /*20 is a number of characters in a string*/
 (SELECT * FROM (SELECT idDepartment FROM Department ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
);
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! I just had to change a few things.

INSERT INTO User (idUser, name, departmentId)
VALUES (seq_user.nextVal, DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('L',20),
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT idDepartment FROM Department ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) WHERE ROWNUM = 1);

Best regards,

Mauricio Urbano.